# Jung: Add legends to the frame

Tags: java, user-interface, jung2

I need to add legends to my frame to show the meaning of different colored links and nodes.
Does Jung have some in built legend functionality? Or do I need make my own by adding an extra panel to the right.

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I added the legends in a simple way. First made an Image of the legends and then stick it to the panel via the JLabel.

```
         JLabel label = new JLabel();
         label.setOpaque(true);
         label.setBackground(Color.WHITE);

         ImageIcon icon = new ImageIcon("Legend/SyncLegend.png");
         label.setIcon(icon);

         vv.add(label);
```

[image]